# WinCE CabWiz error: "inf contains DirIDs, which are not supported"

Tags: installation, windows-ce, cab, cabwiz

When building the windows mobile cab for our product, the windows CE CAB Wizard (CabWiz.exe) sometimes returns the error:

> Error: File
>   c:\docume~1\build\locals~1\temp\wiz3340.inf
>   contains DirIDs, which are not
>   supported

This error can occur when using more than 998 files, ~260 directories, or when a % sign is unescaped (with another %), but these don't apply in our case.

Has anyone run into this issue before?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue today, and found a solution for me that worked here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100330064330/http://blogs.msdn.com/raffael/archive/2008/03/18/x-inf-contains-dirids-which-are-not-supported.aspx

> So I thought: ok, he's hitting the known limit of 998 files that could
>   be packaged in a CAB... Wrong: the problem happened also when using
>   much less files, say 300... I'm still talking about C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\SDKTools\CabWiz.exe, version 4.0.4332.0.
>
> After running some tests, I reached a magic number: 262. With 262
>   files VS2008 could create a Smart Device CAB successfully, with 263
>   files it gave error "x.inf contains DirIDs, which are not supported".
>   At this point I noticed that in the .INF file that VS2008 creates and
>   gives to CabWiz.exe, it wrote an entry under [DestinationDirs] for
>   each added file, even if the target folder on the device is the same,
>   as it was in my case. By manually editing the INF (using some
>   applications that automated lines-creation...), I could successfully
>   create a CAB for 263+ files, specifying only one entry under
>   [DestinationDirs]. So, another limit I wasn't aware of is: VS2008's
>   CabWiz can parse up to 262 different entries under [DestinationDirs].
>
> Now: Windows Mobile 6 SDKs ship with a newer version of CabWiz.exe,
>   v4.5.5102.0 and, very interestingly, it overcame not only the
>   limitation about 998 files, but also the one about 262 entries under
>   [DestinationDirs]. So the "simple" solution in this case was to
>   download one of the 2 Windows Mobile 6 SDKs and use that CabWiz.exe
>   (C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Tools\CabWiz).