# Cab project build error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-mobile

I'm trying to build a CAB project for windows mobile 6.0 and keep getting this error:
"Error: File c:\users...\wiz20a9.inf contains DirIDs, which are not supported" and i have no idea what that message means. a search got me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497453/wince-cabwiz-error-inf-contains-dirids-which-are-not-supported) that sais the problem should have been solved in 6.0 but I'm still getting that message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i found the problem with CAB project, and the problem was indeed the i have reached some sort of limit in "Detected Dependencies". fortunately i has some duplicate dependencies and so i was able to exclude them and pass building CAB project. other way for that is to split the project to several CABs